# MVC using multiple tables , 2 generated with code first and one with DB first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and i think someone answered this question before , so i apologize for re-posting it.
I've been a form based programmers for years , and now i am working on an MVC project for the first time, last 3 weeks i read a lot of books, articles, tutorials and watched a lot of videos about MVC.

Here is my question:
- I have 3 tables: Tasks, Customer and Employee
Each task has 1 customer and one employee assigned to it. I generated the Tasks table from an existing table i have on a SQL DB , but i followed "Code-First" to create the employee and Customer tables.  I am not sure if i did the right relationships between those table. What i want to do is to display all tasks + the userNAME + CustomerName instead of UserID and CustomerID.

Here are my models:

Tasks:

```
public partial class Tasks
{        
    public string TaskID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Complete { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Priority { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AssignementDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey ("Employee")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser _User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerModel _Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Customer:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    [Key]
    public String ID { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }

}
```

Employee

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }


}
```

- Also How to access the employee first name from my Tasks controller.
- Last question: is it ok to mix between models (Some code-first and some DB-first) Or should i follow one pattern.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use both pattern, but I recommend you my approach that you use CodeFirst, create entites to store data and viewmodels to display data:

```
public class Task
{        
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    //your other properties here...

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

And in client lawyer, create ViewModel for `Task` model:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{        
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In your `GetTask()` (Or `LoadTasks()`) method fill this view model:

```
public TaskViewModel GetTask(int id) 
{
   TaskViewModel model = new TaskViewModel();
   model.Task = _db.GetTaskById(id);
   model.Employee = _db.GetEmployeeById(model.Task.EmployeeId);
   model.User = _db.GetUserById(model.Task.UserId);
   model.Customer = _db.GetCustomerById(model.Task.CustomerId);
   return model;
}
```

And now, you can get all data you want related to a task:

```
TaskId, TaskName, Created user's name + surname, Employee's name surname, Custemer's name  + surname etc..
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i don't have the property _db.GetEmployeeById should i add it to my employee controller? The same thing for the other ones _db.GetUserById and _db.GetCustomerById.Also that _db is it the DB context for my tasks?

Comment: That is just idea. you can create that methods inside your dbContext class or you can do that without methods like this: *_db.TaskTable.Where(e=>e.TaskId == id);*. It is a GetTaskById method